Grimm's Law and PIE in general
What's the evidence for stating that the transition from stops to fricatives took place in Proto-Germanic and not that fricatives became stops in the other PIE brances?
The question of this kind applies to all others postulated rules of sound change.

Are you familiar with Occam’s Razor?

@JanusBahsJacquet, yes but please elaborate

The evidence comes in two main forms.
One, some types of sound changes are much more common than their reverse. Stops turn into fricatives more often than fricatives turn into stops. But this isn't a universal rule—fricatives can turn into stops, we see it in German, and some aspects of Grimm's Law (voiced stops becoming unvoiced) are typologically less common than the reverse.
Two, there are a lot of branches of PIE. When only one branch has a particular feature, it's more likely that that feature is an innovation than a preservation—it's more likely that one branch made a change than every other branch. But this one also isn't a universal rule. Anatolian, for example, split off before any other branch, which means differences between Anatolian and the rest could equally well be "post-Anatolian-PIE" innovations.
So it's not always clear! Neither of these methods is foolproof, and there are some open questions where it's unclear which branch's version of a feature is the original one (like the different gender systems in Anatolian and non-Anatolian). But for Grimm's Law, the second point gives us pretty solid evidence that it was a change within Germanic, not in all the other branches.

The ‘exceptions’ to the second point can often be when one branch innovates and then later splits off into multiple branches (as is the case with many differences between Anatolian and ‘post-Anatolian-PIE’, aka Core IE). That wouldn’t work here, though. It would require a stage where IE was just two branches – Germanic and The Other Branch – and since we know in various other ways that Germanic wasn’t the first branch to split off, no such stage ever existed. The stops are also attested about two millennia before the Germanic fricatives.

@JanusBahsJacquet, how is the emergence of a new branch estimated?

@Shpekard In many different ways. One of those ways is precisely features that don’t exist in other branches – while it is theoretically possible that ten different branches all innovate something in the same way, while one branch doesn’t innovate, it would be rather an extraordinary coincidence. The loss of laryngeals did indeed happen independently in quite a few branches, but loss of /h/-like sounds is exceedingly common typologically, so that’s not too surprising, and the reason we can see that it happened separately is precisely that there are differences in how it happened.

It is generally accepted that Anatolian was the first branch to split off, primarily because (1) it’s the earliest attested, (2) it’s the only branch that retains consonantal laryngeals, and (3) there are a number of features shared by all other branches except Anatolian. The most straightforward explanation for (3) is that most of those features arose in Core IE (= the variant that was left when Anatolian had split off); that’s Occam’s Razor. It’s the accumulation of innovations and preservations that allow us to see patterns in which branches share a closer affinity and split off when.
